# How can babies travel from Northern Cyprus (TRNC) to the South (ROC)?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, cyprus, northern-cyprus, disputed-territories

An officer on the Greek side of the Cyprus Green Line told me that a baby being carried by a parent can cross with a birth certificate; no passport or photo ID is required for the baby. I'm wondering:

1. Has anyone done that and can confirm it?
2. Is that also true for the Turkish side of the border?
3. Is there a web source that can confirm this, perhaps in Greek or Turkish?
4. Does that work for all citizenships and birth certificates, or only Cyprus certificates? Even with the birth certificates of the TRNC?